# Wordpress: Wrap HTML/PHP in a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

New to wordpress and PHP.

How do I wrap this shortcode around some HTML/PHP? I've tried using the do_shortcode but that didn't work.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( [timed-content-rule id="101"] ) ?> 

<?php echo do_shortcode( [/timed-content-rule] ) ?>
```

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php
$rows = get_field('breakfast');
$row_count = count($rows);
$i = rand(0, $row_count - 1);

?>

<h1>
    <?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_name']; ?>
</h1>
<p>
   <?php echo $rows[ $i ]['dish_description'];  ?>
</p>
<h3>
    Served<span><?php echo $rows[ $i ]['time_served'];  ?></span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not "wrap" a shortcode around PHP (unless you are planning on it not doing anything).  Shortcodes are designed to produce strings of client side code (HTML, CSS, Javascript, ect...) I would recommend reviewing the [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to figure out how to use a shortcode to produce your output instead of trying to wrap shortcode around it.

So for example let's say you wanted some content to only show up after a certain amount of time... You could use your shortcode to produce the content (HTML) and make sure it has an "ID" or "CLASS" that a piece of javascript (or jQuery) is looking for.  When the javascript sees that "CLASS" it knows to set it's display to none for so many seconds before changing it to block or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on the wordpress page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

```
echo do_shortcode('[iscorrect]'.$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode.'[/iscorrect]');
```

in your case you could add your html to a variable then add that in ie:

```
$contentToShow = '<h1>'.$rows[ $i ]['dish_name'].'</h1>';
$contentToShow.= '<p>'.$rows[ $i ]['dish_description'].'</p>';
$contentToShow.= '<h3>Served<span>'.$rows[ $i ]['time_served'].'</span></h3>';

echo do_shortcode('[timed-content-rule]'.$contentToShow.'[/timed-content-rule]');
```

Marty

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work. I think it has to do with the answer @Cleanshooter gave.